# Looping through all files in a given directory

Tags: shell

Here is what I'm trying to do:

Give a parameter to a shell script that will run a task on all files of jpg, bmp, tif extension.

Eg: ./doProcess /media/repo/user1/dir5

and all jpg, bmp, tif files in that directory will have a certain task run on them.

What I have now is:

```
for f in *
do
  imagejob "$f"  "output/${f%.output}" ;
done
```

I need help with the for loop to restrict the file types and also have some way of starting under a specified directory instead of current directory.

Answer (score 6):

Use shell expansion rather than `ls`

```
for file in *.{jpg,bmp,tif}
do
  imagejob "$file" "output/${file%.output}"
done
```

also if you have bash 4.0+, you can use `globstar`

```
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s nocaseglob
for file in **/*.{jpg,bmp,tif}
do
  # do something with $file
done
```

Comment: +1 You're missing a closing quote.

Comment: how do i specify the directory to run this script under?

Comment: im getting an error cannot stat `*.{jpg,bmp,tif}': No such file or directory

Comment: This solution doesn't work for directories containing a large number of files; it fails with the error "Argument list too long".

Comment: I may be mistaken about that, sorry.

Comment: For reference, the shell expansion used here is called [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html). It's not defined in POSIX, but is supported by several different shells. Be aware that if no file is found for the pattern, the pattern itself is returned. For example, if there are no files with a `.jpg` extension, the value of `$file`, on the first loop, will be the literal string `*.jpg`. If you have Bash, you can avoid this with the `nullglob` option as shown in the second example.

Comment: @ash The filename expansion is done relative to the current directory. You can specify a subdirectory as part of the pattern. You can also specify an absolute path. For example,  `/path/to/files/*.{jpg,bmp,tif}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `ls $1/*.jpg $1/*.bmp $1/*.tif`; do
    imagejob "$i";
done
```

This is assuming you're using a bashlike shell where `$1` is the first argument given to it.

You could also do:

```
find "$1" -iname "*.jpg" -or -iname "*.bmp" -or -iname "*.tif" \
          -exec imagejob \{\} \;
```

Comment: using `ls` to list files with a for loop is bad practice

Comment: The find solution is nice but will find names recursively. The shell globbing method might break with spaces in file names.

Comment: The curly braces don't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a construct with backticks and ls (or any other commando of course):

```
for f in `ls *.jpg *.bmp *.tif`; do ...; done
```

Comment: using `ls` to list files with a for loop is bad practice

Comment: for what reasons exactly? I know it's a problem with spaces, and very large dirs, but it seems sufficient for other cases.

I think your solution is better in this case, but what if I want to use sorting options of ls/pipe its output through another command?

Comment: it's to prevent future cases of whitespaces in file names. (Also, its what people call, useless  use of `ls`). Why wait for your code to break when you can prevent it in the first place. If you need to use other options coupled with `ls`, use a while read loop (or you can set IFS )

Comment: See "reasons exactly," see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions here are either Bash-only or recommend the use of `ls` in spite of it being [a common and well-documented antipattern](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  Here is how to solve this in POSIX `sh` without `ls`:

```
for file in *.jpg *.bmp *.tif; do
    ... stuff with "$file"
done
```

If you have a very large number of files, perhaps you also want to look into

```
find . -maxdepth -type f \( \
    -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.bmp' -o -name '*.tif' \) \
    -exec stuff with {} +
```

which avoids the overhead of sorting the file names alphabetically.  The `-maxdepth 1` says to not recurse into subdirectories; obviously, take it out or modify it if you do want to recurse into subdirectories.

The `-exec ... +` predicate of `find` is a relatively new introduction; if your `find` is too old, you might want to use `-exec ... \;` or replace the `-exec stuff with {} +` with

```
find ... -print0 |
xargs -r0 stuff with
```

where however again the `-print0` option and the corresponding `-0` option for `xargs` are a GNU extension.